# How to run mysql_upgrade on mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, upgrade

Is there anyway to run `mysql_upgrade` on mysql workbench?
Or it can be run only on command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mysql_upgrade** is a shell script and does not have a GUI interface from MySQL Workbench. Run it from the command line (depending on your operating system).